# What to do after Wine install?

Tags: software-installation, wine, executable

I have installed Wine using the following:

```
sudo apt-get i wine
```

I have got the files installed. Now, my question is the following:

How can I proceed further to open my **.exe** files?

Answer (score 4):

command line:

```
wine /dir/to/application.exe
```

There is also a menu entry in Nautilus called "open with wine windows program loader"

An MSI installer is done with

```
wine msiexec /i /dir/to/installer.msi
```

Do not forget to install `winetricks` and if you want games `playonlinux`.

And to configure wine: hit super and search for wine.

Mileage may vary per exe file so do check out  [WineHQ](http://appdb.winehq.org/) for tips and tricks regarding software, rating on how well software functions.

Answer (score 3):

Click on the exe file and Wine should open it automatically. If it doesn't,then right-click on exe file and choose 'Open with Wine'.